# Append '|' after every array element

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have this JSON & what I want to do is to make genres like this action|adventure|comedy

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "key": "deadpool",
        "name": "Deadpool",
        "description": "A former Special Forces operative turned mercenary is subjected to a rogue experiment that leaves him with accelerated healing powers, adopting the alter ego Deadpool.",
        "genres": [
            "action",
            "adventure",
            "comedy"
        ],
        "rate": 8.6,
        "length": "1hr 48mins",
        "img": "assets/images/movie-covers/deadpool.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "key": "we-are-the-millers",
        "name": "We're the Millers",
        "description": "A veteran pot dealer creates a fake family as part of his plan to move a huge shipment of weed into the U.S. from Mexico.",
        "genres": [
            "adventure",
            "comedy",
            "crime"
        ],
        "rate": 7,
        "length": "1hr 50mins",
        "img": "assets/images/movie-covers/we-are-the-millers.jpg"
    }
```

my component code snippet

```
           data => {
                this.movies = data;
                var tempArr= data
                var genres;
               let genresWithPipe=[];          
                let len= tempArr.length;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    genres=tempArr[i].genres+'|';
                   // console.log(tempArr[i].genres)
                 for(var j=0;j<genres.length; j++){
                    if(j<genres.length-1)
                    genres[j]= genres[j]+'|';
                    console.log(genres,data);
                    //genresWithPipe=genres;
                }
                }
                console.log(this.movies,genres)


            }
```

I have tried to do it with the help of for loop in my component but then when I am displaying it in the html with the help of *ngFor then because it's a local variable,it won't show up. If I store array values in a global variable then the variable only store the last array.

Comment: You need to add html snippet code about how you are using it to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` method in order to **achieve** your requirement and obtain a more cleaner solution.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

Also, you can use `join` method in order to obtain the structure `action|adventure|comedy` with `|` delimiter.

```js
let array=[{ "id": 1, "key": "deadpool", "name": "Deadpool", "description": "A former Special Forces operative turned mercenary is subjected to a rogue experiment that leaves him with accelerated healing powers, adopting the alter ego Deadpool.", "genres": [ "action", "adventure", "comedy" ], "rate": 8.6, "length": "1hr 48mins", "img": "assets/images/movie-covers/deadpool.jpg" }, { "id": 2, "key": "we-are-the-millers", "name": "We're the Millers", "description": "A veteran pot dealer creates a fake family as part of his plan to move a huge shipment of weed into the U.S. from Mexico.", "genres": [ "adventure", "comedy", "crime" ], "rate": 7, "length": "1hr 50mins", "img": "assets/images/movie-covers/we-are-the-millers.jpg" }];       
 array=array.map(function(item){
    item.genres=item.genres.join('|');
    return item;
 });
 console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

A good solution with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has been proposed, here is another option with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "key": "deadpool",
    "name": "Deadpool",
    "description": "A former Special Forces operative turned mercenary is subjected to a rogue experiment that leaves him with accelerated healing powers, adopting the alter ego Deadpool.",
    "genres": [
      "action",
      "adventure",
      "comedy"
    ],
    "rate": 8.6,
    "length": "1hr 48mins",
    "img": "assets/images/movie-covers/deadpool.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "key": "we-are-the-millers",
    "name": "We're the Millers",
    "description": "A veteran pot dealer creates a fake family as part of his plan to move a huge shipment of weed into the U.S. from Mexico.",
    "genres": [
      "adventure",
      "comedy",
      "crime"
    ],
    "rate": 7,
    "length": "1hr 50mins",
    "img": "assets/images/movie-covers/we-are-the-millers.jpg"
  }
]

const genres = [];
data.forEach(film => genres.push(film.genres.join("|")));

console.dir(genres);
```

Note that your `data` definitely doesn't look like what you put in the code sample, it *must* be wrapped with `[]`.